# How to get the actual view rendered size and position in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The question is how to get the actual viewed rendered size and position in a parent view? In other word, how to get the actual `Text("Foo")` size in the SwiftUI code below?

[`GeometryReader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader)  can be used to get the parent proposed `size` and safe area inset via `safeAreaInsets` and these information is defined inside [`GeometryProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryproxy). You can see from the screenshot below, the proposed size to `VStack` is `300` width and `300` height and the actual size for the `VStack` is unknown.

[image]

```
struct FooView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            VStack {
                Text("\(geometryProxy.size.height), \(geometryProxy.size.width)")
                Text("Foo")
            }
            .background(Color.green)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Actual Rendered Size**

The workaround is to get the actual rendered size via `.background` modifier with an nested `GeometryReader`. The size information inside the new geometry proxy can then be stored in  a temporary `@State` variable defined in the View.

```
struct FooSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue = CGSize.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct FooView: View {
    @State private var fooSize: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            VStack {
                Text("\(self.fooSize.height), \(self.fooSize.width)")
                Text("Foo")
                    .background(
                        GeometryReader { fooProxy in
                            Color
                                .green
                                .preference(key: FooSizePreferenceKey.self,
                                            value: fooProxy.size)
                                .onPreferenceChange(FooSizePreferenceKey.self) { size in
                                    self.fooSize = size
                            }
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[image]

**Actual Rendered Position**

The actual rendered position for the view can be calculated using `Anchor` and `anchorPreference`. Using the anchor and the parent `geometryProxy`, we can easily get the position `.bound` information of the target view.

```
struct FooAnchorData: Equatable {
    var anchor: Anchor<CGRect>? = nil
    static func == (lhs: FooAnchorData, rhs: FooAnchorData) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

struct FooAnchorPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue = FooAnchorData()
    static func reduce(value: inout FooAnchorData, nextValue: () -> FooAnchorData) {
        value.anchor = nextValue().anchor ?? value.anchor
    }
}

struct FooView: View {
    @State private var foo: CGPoint = .zero

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            VStack {
                Text("\(self.foo.x), \(self.foo.y)")
                Text("Foo")
                    .background(
                        GeometryReader { fooProxy in
                            Color
                                .green
                                .anchorPreference(key: FooAnchorPreferenceKey.self,
                                                  value: .bounds,
                                                  transform: {FooAnchorData(anchor: $0) })
                                .onPreferenceChange(FooAnchorPreferenceKey.self) { data in
                                    self.foo = geometryProxy[data.anchor!].origin
                            }
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining this API, since it's completely undocumented. =(

Comment: These are Apple standards of documenting stuff.